# Sorting a list of lists in python TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have this line of code which is giving me the error, any idea why? `swap_avg_by_hour` is a list of lists.

```
  swap_avg_by_hour = [['21', 16.009174311926607],
     ['12', 9.41095890410959],
     ['10', 13.440677966101696],
     ['05', 10.08695652173913],
     ['09', 5.5777777777777775],
     ['15', 38.5948275862069]]

    sorted_swap = sorted(swap_avg_by_hour,reverse=True)



TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-d3b6bff69d90> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted_swap = sorted(swap_avg_by_hour,reverse=True)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you have a list called `sorted` defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Ardweaden he does, definitly ;-)

Comment: no guys i have no list or variable whatsoever called sorted

Comment: You're using Jupyter notebook, right? Did you _ever_ have a list called `sorted`? You should restart your kernel and try this line of code again.

Comment: Sure helped, I restarted the kernel and my code works just fine. Many thanks

Comment: @dspencer I've been working on the same issue as OP for HOURS. Restarted the kernel and it's immediately fine. Ugh!

Comment: @user2954167 Since this helped you too, I've written it up as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to work just fine.

Which version of Python are you running?

This error means that sorted is a `list`, make sure you don't have any variable called sorted in your interpreter.

Try to reopen Python's interpreter, or just `print(sorted)` to see if it is already defined.

Comment: Im using jupyter notebook,restarting my kernel helped

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your Jupyter Notebook, you previously defined a variable named `sorted` to be a list (even though you deleted the line/cell which defined this, the variable still exists). In doing so, this "hides" the built-in `sorted` function, giving you the error

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

If you restart your Jupyter Notebook kernel, this will clear all definitions in memory and you should find that you can execute the built-in function `sorted` as you expected.